# Why does gpg skip secret keys that don't have a public key?

Tags: gpg

I have a secret key in my keyring, but I do not have the corresponding public key. When I try to decrypt a file, I get the message:

```
gpg: key XXXXXXXX: secret key without public key - skipped
```

Could gpg not generate the public key from the secret key? Is this a intentional design choice of gpg to skip the key even if it could theoretically be used? If so, what's the reasoning?